# How to store data temporarily while redirectring within 2 OAuth Steps

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, server

I've read a lot of questions and look after a lot of sources, but I could not get the idea. That's because there is lot redirects happening with my application, let's see a quick look over the steps.

> Step1. Login with [MyApp1]
> 1.1 get tokens via POST method

> Step2. [Save tokens temporarily] < Stuck here.

> Step3. Login with [MyApp2]
> 3.1 get tokens via POST method

> Step4. Encrypt all tokens
> 4.1 Save it to MySQL Database

I do not know what is best to save the data temporarily, I looked over *sessions* and *Redis*, **I am working on Node.js Web Application, HTML with a Server and MySQL Database.**

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps store them in the query? OAuth2 provides a `state` query parameter that is applied on redirect so your application can pass some information to itself after redirecting.

Comment: it is providing a `state` query parameter, but It will have 4 redirects, 1. webpage to MyApp1, 2. MyApp1 to webpage [TOKEN], 3. webpage to MyApp2, 4. MyApp2 to webpage[TOKEN2]. the main idea that i want to make sure that the user who entered MyApp1 is the same who entered MyApp2, to safely store tokens in MySQL. it is a double question. By the way I do not have access to change query for both MyApp1 or MyApp2. So I cannot pass informations